# QGIS Refactor fields curiosity

Tags: qgis, geopackage, refactor

**Background:**

At 3.18.2 I have a Geopackage attribute table that I want to refactor, as shown in the screenshot below.  I want to limit the field *box_id* length to 8.

The table currently has 55 records, but will soon have tens of thousands.

[image]

**Problem:**

The refactoring correctly adjusts the field length.  However, it **also** changes the *fid* field from **Int64** to **Int8**, as shown in the screenshot below.  Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?  Neither the QGIS docs, nor SE GIS, address this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created an empty point geopackage file and refactored the fields. I cannot reproduce this problem in QGIS 3.18.2-Zürich.

**Update: Indeed, when the text field is filled with values - refactoring converts `fid` to `int8`.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmmm.  What happens if you add a few records and retry?

Comment: Also, what QGIS version are you using?

Comment: @StuSmith QGIS version 3.18.2-Zürich

Comment: @StuSmith Indeed, when the text field is filled with values - refactoring converts `fid` to `int8`.

Comment: @StuSmith I suggest you create a issue here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Thanks for you research!  I've submitted a bug report at: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43437

Comment: Hi @Comrade Che, you might want to look at the github bug report for the latest info!